# Not Getting All href links with invoke-webrequest

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I use this script to login to a website:

```
$r = Invoke-WebRequest 'https://www.slika-ins.co.il/Login.aspx' -SessionVariable sat
$form = $r.Forms[0]
$form.fields["MainContent_txtUserName"] = "xxx"
$form.fields["MainContent_txtPassword"] = "xxx"

$login=Invoke-WebRequest -Uri ("https://www.slika-ins.co.il/" + $form.Action) -WebSession $sat -Method POST -Body $form.Fields
```

When i'm running the command `$login.Links.href` I don't get all the possible links.

However, when I'm using the ComObject of "InternetExplorer.Application" I get all the possible links.

Comment: Look at `$r.Content`, is this complete? Invoke-WebRequest will not invoke Js, so you don't get any manipulations from the js, but InternetExplorer.Application will invoke JS.

Comment: yes, the $r.content is complete.

Comment: yes, the $r.content is complete. about the InternetExplorer.Application - it's not good enough for me because I want to run this script as a TaskScheduled, you have another idea? eg : WebClient